# Contact form with jquery ajax php

Tags: jquery, json, ajaxform

I have a contact form with jquery and ajax submission method. The code works perfectly for me in one of my sites. The same code, which used to run ok before has started to give me problems on another site.

> in chrome it reads "There was a SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in
>   JSON at position 0 error due to a parse error condition."
>
> in firefox it reads"There was an SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected
>   character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data error due to a
>   parse error condition."

Please let me know why this might be happening.

here is my js code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.contact-page #response').hide();

$('#submit').click(function(e) {

    // prevent forms default action until
    // error check has been performed
    e.preventDefault();

    // grab form field values
    var valid = '';
    var required = ' is required.';
    var name = $('#name').val();
    var email = $('#email').val();
    var message = $('#message').val();
var phone = $('#phone').val();
    var honeypot = $('#honeypot').val();
    var humancheck = $('#humancheck').val();

    // perform error checking
    if (name = '' || name.length <= 2) {
        valid = '<p>Your name' + required +'</p>';
    }

    if (!email.match(/^([a-z0-9._-]+@[a-z0-9._-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$)/i)) {
        valid += '<p>Your email' + required +'</p>';
    }

     if (phone = '' || phone.length <= 8){
        valid += '<p>A working phone number' + required +'</p>';
    }

    if (message = '' || message.length <= 5) {
        valid += '<p>A message' + required + '</p>';
    }

    if (honeypot != 'http://') {
        valid += '<p>Spambots are not allowed.</p>';
    }

    if (humancheck != '') {
        valid += '<p>A human user' + required + '</p>';
    }

    // let the user know if there are errors with the form
    if (valid != '') {

        $('.contact-page #response').removeClass().addClass('error').html('<p style="color:black"><strong>Please correct the errors.</strong></p>' +valid).fadeIn('fast');
    }
    // let the user know something is happening behind the scenes
    // serialize the form data and send to our ajax function
    else {

        $('.contact-page #response').removeClass().addClass('processing').html('<p style="color:white; font-weight:bold;">Processing your submission...</p>').fadeIn('fast');

        var formData = $('form').serialize();
        submitForm(formData);
    }

});
});
```

// make our ajax request to the server

```
function submitForm(formData) {
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'contactform.php',
    data: formData,
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    timeout: 7000,
    success: function(data) {

        $('.contact-page #response').removeClass().addClass((data.error === true) ? 'error' : 'success')
                    .html(data.msg).fadeIn('fast');

        if ($('.contact-page #response').hasClass('success')) {

            setTimeout("$('.contact-page #response').fadeOut('fast')", 5000);
        }

    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

        $('.contact-page #response').removeClass().addClass('error')
                    .html('<p>There was an<strong> ' + errorThrown +
                          '</strong> error due to a<strong> ' + textStatus +
                          '</strong> condition.</p>').fadeIn('fast');
    },
    complete: function(XMLHttpRequest, status) {

        $('form')[0].reset();
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Can you update js code here? so, it's easy to find a solution.

Comment: ive just updated the code. Im new to coding. I got this from some place which i dont seem to remember.  @VishalMaru can u help me?